# XML parsing in MYSQL Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, xml

i have an xml whose node names are preceeded with the namespaces. these namespaces are not consistent and may vary. how to extract value of a node in mysql stored procedure without hard coding the namespaces.

Ex XML:

```html
<ns1:token>
   <ns2:id>12</ns2:id>
</ns1:token>
```

Ex mysql:
I am able to read the value of 'id' in stored proc as below

```
set id=ExtractValue(xml,'//ns1:token//ns2:id');
```

but, i don't want ns1/ns2 to be hard coded as they may be expected as not same all the time. Any body has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to ignore the namespace in MySQL XML functions. While the second parameter to ExtractValue is an XPath string, it doesn't support the full XPath functionality, so things like `//*:token//*:id` or `//*[local-name()='token']//*[local-name()='id']` don't work.

Anyway, the namespace is as much a part of the XML as is the tag name. If you want to do proper XML handling, you shouldn't ignore the namespace. It's no different than saying that you wouldn't want tag names to be hardcoded because they aren't expected to be the same all the time.